# Wordpress: replace custom taxonomy title term with term including HTML markup via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

On a Wordpress site we have created a custom taxonomy „n2sproducts“ which has a taxonomy term „Premium Solarzaun2“.
This term has to be displayed on the frontend with the „2“ as superscript – HTML code Premium Solarzaun<sup>2</sup>
When entering the taxonomy title in the backend with HTML markup, the markup is stripped by Wordpress when saving the term.

We already tried

```
    function change_translate_text( $replaced_text ) {
    if ( 'Premium Solarzaun2'  === $replaced_text ) {
        $replaced_text = 'Premium Solarzaun<sup>2</sup>';
    }
    return $replaced_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_translate_text', 20 );
```

and also this

```
function taxonomy_title( $title ){
if( is_taxonomy('n2sproducts') ){
    $title = 'Premium Solarzaun<sup>2</sup>';
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'taxonomy_title' );
```

but this does not work.
Can someone please help out with a code snippet for the functions.php.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be a `sup` element, a simple `²` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: _"but this does not work"_ - in what way? Get the `<sup>` shown as text? Then this is probably an issue of the archive title getting HTML escaping applied in the template.

Comment: does not work: The term is still displayed with a regular "2" and not with the "2" placed as superscript.
from my point of view we need the HMTL markup because on the site we have the terms "Premium Solarzaun" and "Premium Solarzaun<sup>2</sup>

Comment: But why don't you simply name your term `Premium Solarzaun²` to begin with then?

Comment: how can we "superscript" the 2 (so that it stands on top of the line of the letters) so that it is saved in wordpress accordingly?
When entering the string (e.g. from a word doc) the wordpress fiel automatically converts it to a regular 2 - see: https://prnt.sc/Cy7Uo0rVmHjX

Comment: If WP automatically replaces `²` with a `2` when saving, then you would need to either disable that (there's probably a hook for sanitizing the post title when saving), or if that is not possible/not desired, you will need to find the place in the template(s) where this actually gets output, and see what filters get applied there.